# Correct architecture for a reliant Windows EC2 background worker on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, architecture, amazon-ec2, redis

Basically we save cached data on Redis and we want to dump it into MongoDB every X seconds.

We have a sorted set stored on Redis, saving each user's last activity as score, and we want to periodically dump user's final state after being inactive for a certain period of time, and we wish to make sure that:

1. We don't strain our API servers (That's why it has to run on a worker instance.
2. The data dump operation is very critical - We require these worker instances to be scalable and highly resilient to failure (and should handle failure gracefully).
3. We must ensure that if we have X machines, that the data would be spread across instances, and that every item we pull from Redis will be handled **exactly** once.

I was wondering what would be the best architectural approach to deploy EC2 Windows instances that periodically handle data.

I was thinking of using Elastic Beanstalk as it's easy to deploy, scale & monitor, but I was wondering if there was a better approach to this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Other than the application, for which Amazon Elastic Beanstalk is a fine choice, i'd recommend you take a look at Amazon Kinesis: http://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/

That is because you mentioned "scalable", "resilient", "handle failure gracefully" and "exactly once". Those attributes are quite hard to get right in a distributed system, and Kinesis Streams and Client Library can greatly help with that.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll take a look at it and mark this as an answer if it's a solid solution